# Adding additional layer of Schema Registry out weights benefits?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Are there any benefits to adding an additional layer (aka point of failure) of Schema Registry when producing/consumer messages? If the service ever goes down, then messages won't be consumed or produced. Wouldn't the system using Kafka less prone to errors by not using Schema Registry which gives one less point of failure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One key point of having a schema registry in your architecture is to ensure that your data pipelines are working end-to-end "even during normal operations".

That is, even when all systems are up and running ("all green, 100% uptime!"), a producer application managed by team `A`, for example, might get updated and now start to generate incompatible data that causes collateral damage to downstream consumers managed by teams `B` and `C` that weren't expecting this change.

So when you are making a decision whether or not to use a schema registry, you should not only ask yourself about the scenario "when things fail" (which most probably will happen at some point, that's why e.g. Confluent Schema Registry supports features like a high availability setup), but also about the guarantees you need for your data pipelines work in general.

> If the service ever goes down, then messages won't be consumed or produced.

In general, yes.  In practice, features such as high availability modes for the schema registry service, client-side caching of schemas, etc. all help to minimize any such damage.

> Wouldn't the system using Kafka less prone to errors by not using Schema Registry which gives one less point of failure?

You are right that, in general, you'd want to avoid introducing a component that would be another point of failure in the chain.

That said, if you are running data pipelines in production -- particularly in a larger organization -- a schema registry also helps to remove "points of failures" by ensuring that data that is written can also always be read.  One could argue that failures triggered by "data changes" can be at least as common as failures triggered by the unavailability of one or more systems.

Answer (score 3):

The schema registry can be configured to be [highly available](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/schema-registry/docs/design.html#single-master-architecture) so it is not a single point of failure.

That said, if you want the convenience and schema compatibility rules that come with the schema registry then you want to use it. Not all clients connecting to a Kafka cluster are required to use it, so you can try it without impacting other clients on the same cluster.

Your main alternative to using the schema registry for avro message is to add the schema to the message itself. Some users are OK with the larger message size and not systematically evolving schemas. The schema registry is for those that are concerned with such things.